# Changing Registry ACL rights for all user access

Tags: delphi, registry, acl

Some years ago, we encountered problems where an administrator would install our application on a user's machine Our app would create registry entries at the time of install, but would then fail due to registry registry rights when a *different* user ran our application.

The code below was written by a predecessor. It seems to fixed the above problem. But recently, the code below itself began to fail gracefully, reporting a Windows error: "Failed Key" on the `SetSecurityDescriptorDacl` call.

This seems to happen on networked machines which have a corporate group policy in place. We suspect that the call to `SetSecurityDescriptorDacl` with nil may not legal on these machines, even if the user has admin rights.

This is not an area that we have any expertise in, so I'm hoping someone will have some ideas or an alternate code snippet that lets us circumvent this problem...

```
    class function TQPWindowsRegistry.GiveEveryoneFullAccessToRegistryKey(  const RootKey: HKey;
                                                                            const RegPath : string;
                                                                            out ErrorMsg : string): boolean;
    var
      Access : LongWord;
      WinResult : LongWord;
      SD : PSecurity_Descriptor;
      LastError : DWORD;
      Reg : TRegistry;
    begin
      Result := TRUE;
      ErrorMsg := '';
      if (Win32Platform = VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT) then
        begin
          if TOOLS.UserHasAdminToken then
            Access := KEY_ALL_ACCESS
          else
            Access := KEY_READ OR KEY_WRITE;

          Reg := TRegistry.Create(Access);
          try
            Reg.RootKey := RootKey;
            if NOT Reg.OpenKey(RegPath, TRUE) then
              Exit;
            GetMem(SD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
            try
              Result := InitializeSecurityDescriptor(SD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
              if Result then
                Result := SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(SD, TRUE, NIL, FALSE); // Fails here!
              if NOT Result then
                begin
                  LastError := WINDOWS.GetLastError;
                  if NOT Result then
                    ErrorMsg := SYSUTILS.SysErrorMessage(LastError);
                end
              else
                begin
                  WinResult := RegSetKeySecurity(Reg.CurrentKey, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, SD);
                  Result := (WinResult = ERROR_SUCCESS);
                  ErrorMsg := SYSUTILS.SysErrorMessage(WinResult);
                end;
            finally
              FreeMem(SD);
            end;
            Reg.CloseKey;
          finally
            FreeAndNIL(Reg);
          end;
        end;
    end; {GiveEveryoneFullAccessToRegistryKey}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would have a need to give all users full access to any part of the registry. This violates all of the UAC and security improvements to Windows since XP was released Anything that should be **read** by all users but not written should go in `HKEY_USERS`, and anything that should be written by a user should go in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. Anything that should be read/write for all users doesn't belong in the registry; it goes in `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` (pre-Vista) or `FOLDERID_PUBLIC` (Vista and later). If you're doing it otherwise, you're setting yourself up for headaches.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Ken. I agree with you. We shouldn't need to go as deeply into this.   We've abandoned using the registry in any new code, but I'm stuck with this legacy code. which as you point out, violates current standards.

Comment: <g> I figured as much; that's why I just posted a comment. It's a pet peeve of mine because of issues at work caused by someone who refuses to update his thought process; we've been going around and around because of UAC and Win7 and Windows Server 2003/2008 lately. Sorry to vent on you. :)

Comment: Change the legacy code so it doesn't need an acl. Acls in the registry are evil.

Comment: ACLs in the registry are not evil as long as you use it to **increase** security, not to decrease it. Anyway I still wonder how many developers facing a problem involving security usually attempt to choose the way that would cripple it and not the one that would not. Then people complain "Windows in not secure".

Comment: Alas, David, I wish that modifying the legacy code was easier than it is.  Thus my hope to circumvent that task with an ACL change. I, as usual, agree with you!